# What utilities exist to brute force a username and password?

Tags: brute-force, vpn

I'm trying to persuade management to purchase two factor authentication for securing VPN and terminal server access.

I've made significant progress by demoing TSGrinder, but would like to list other utilities as well.  What other similar utilities exist for the same purpose, but for a different software stack Nortel VPN, etc...?

Answer (score 4):

[THC-Hydra](http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra/) might be helpful here.

Also [Bruter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/worawita/).

I have not used them for VPN or TS testing, but they are the 'standard' Windows password brute force tools.

Answer (score 4):

If your VPN is worth anything, brute forcing it is going to just result in an account lockout, so you won't really prove a point.

What two factor authentication will more likely help, is a breach of the password itself (user writes it down and loses it, keyloggers, etc.), of course these are dependent on what is used as the second phase of authentication (ex: answering a personal question is useless against a keylogger, but a user is unlikely to write it down, token generators are good from a lot of stances [minus when they get cracked]).

Comment: whether a lockout is likely depends somewhat on how many users there are and how easy it is to predict usernames.  With a large population (say 10000) and a weak password policy you can get a good chance of getting into someones account event if you only make two guesses per user (which is pretty unlikely to trip a lockout)

Comment: You're saying enterprise firewalls fail to implement their own version of fail2ban?

Comment: @StrangeWill Are you making a bet with me that I won't find some that don't?

Comment: I'm genuinely curious, I'm a bit more from Linux then from Cisco and the like, so stuff like fail2ban on machines that are expected to be hammered (PBX systems, firewalls, etc.) is expected, and I was _hoping_ it was standard on the firewall end of stuff.

Comment: Well I do testing quite a bit and I rarely run into that sort of rate limiting.  I'd agree somewhat surprising, but there it is.

Answer (score 1):

[Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/) Web vulnerability scanner. It has an "Authenticaton tester" which includes the ability to customize the UN/PW lists.

If you run through a proxy pool/chain or, through TOR/i2p/freenet you can generally scramble your location but, your speed would be decreased. I'm sure there are some clever hacks on how to optimize traffic.

Stealth... Another big one, and I would suggest the use of a random WIFI hotpot for your attacks. Perhaps use a VPS on the cloud.

Comment: I'm not sure that the OP was concerned about anonymity, and Acunetix won't help with Terminal Server.